# ExternalAccessory streams delegate not always called in background

Tags: objective-c, ios, bluetooth, external-accessory

I am experiencing a bad issue with the **EA framework**.
Everything is working **when the app is in foreground**, when the accessory, I open a session, retrieve the streams, set their delegate and schedule the streams on the main run-loop

The accessory is pinging my iPhone every second, and these pings are read with the stream delegate. This ping is a kind of heartbeat : if the iPhone does not received any ping in for seconds, the user is alerted.

This app should work in background, so I have added the corresponding keys in my plist file

When the app run in background, everything work fine for 10-30 minutes, and suddenly, for 7-8  seconds, the stream delegate is not called ( but the ping is sent from the accessory), and then in one second, the delegate is called eight times (for all the pings sent during the last seconds)
It looks like my app is suspended for eight seconds,  and then all the events that occured during this interval are queued, and then delivered later. The problem is that, as the application does not received any ping during these 8 seconds, the user is incorrectly alerted

I dont understand this behaviour. Does anybody ecounters the same issue ?
I am considering to poll the stream via a background thread, instead of scheduling them on the main run-loop.

Thanks,

Comment: Ok it seems that there is an issue with iOS, as it choose to coalesce bluetooth events, when a lot of things are happening (Network, etc...)